# plotting 2 datasets with unequal lengths using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 datasets with unequal lengths for plotting using ggplots2:

```
Data A;

column x column y
0.23     1.54    
0.44     1.46
0.69     1.37
0.70     1.21
0.75     1.01
0.88     0.91 

Data B:

column x column y
0.13     1.24    
0.34     1.16
0.49     1.07
0.54     0.99
0.69     1.01
```

I'm sure of how to write a code in ggplot2 for plotting these two data sets together. In both cases, plots shown as x axis = column x and y axis= column y. Can someone help me please?

James

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thank you Chase and user2194122, I got the two codes to work. But, I'm left with two problems still. I will like to be able to control the point color and size(example one dataset points with big blue and the other with small red), and how to suppress the column name read from the data and instead display longer names on x and y axes.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have datasets A and B as a data.frame:

```
A <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=11:15)
B <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=20:11)
```

You have to join them together:

```
df <- rbind(A, B) # Join A and B together.
df
    x  y
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 13
4   4 14
5   5 15
6   1 20
7   2 19
8   3 18
9   4 17
10  5 16
11  6 15
12  7 14
13  8 13
14  9 12
15 10 11
```

Then you can plot it:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
```

If you want to distinguish points from dataset A and B by color:

```
df$dataset <- c(rep("A", nrow(A)), rep("B", nrow(B)))
df
    x  y dataset
1   1 11       A
2   2 12       A
3   3 13       A
4   4 14       A
5   5 15       A
6   1 20       B
7   2 19       B
8   3 18       B
9   4 17       B
10  5 16       B
11  6 15       B
12  7 14       B
13  8 13       B
14  9 12       B
15 10 11       B

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, col=dataset)) + geom_point()
```

If you want to distinguish points from dataset A and B by color and size and change axis labels:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, col=dataset, size=dataset)) + geom_point() +
scale_color_manual(name="Dataset", labels = c("Data A","Data B"), values=c("red", "blue")) + 
scale_size_manual(name="Dataset", labels = c("Data A","Data B"), values=c(10, 5)) + 
xlab("xxxx") + ylab("yyyy")
```

See [Tutorial](https://github.com/echen/ggplot2-tutorial) or use google :).

Comment: `lattice::make.groups(A, B)` makes it easier to add an id variable

Comment: That works fine too.  Ireaaly appreciate your help and the tutorial link info'ggplot(data=df, aes(x=col1, y=col2, col=dataset, size=dataset)) + geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(name="dataset", labels = c("d1","d2"), values=c("blue", "darkgreen")) + 
  scale_size_manual(name="dataset", labels = c("d1","d2"), values=c(10, 5)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_text(data = df,aes(x=col1,y=col2, label=d1)) + 
  xlab("xxxx") + ylab("yyyy")'

Answer (score 3):

I know this comes up all the time when looking to plot data points (which are sparse) and a a line from a theoretical curve (which has lots of data points)

In this case you can give the different aesthetic mappings to each piece of ggplot's geometries, individually.

E.g. [EDITED HERE TO MAKE THE BEST EXAMPLE BE FIRST]

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df_A, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_line(data = df_B, aes(x, y), color = "red") +
  theme_minimal()
```

or

```
ggplot() +
  with(df_A, geom_point(aes(x, y))) + 
  with(df_B, geom_line(aes(x, y)), color = "red") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I would strongly recommend against the use of subsetting functions such as `$` in the `aes` call. It basically works against the principle of  grouping by aesthetic in ggplot2. The second option would be the way to go, although I hvae not yet seen the use of `with` in this context, and I am not sure if this is clever. I'd stick to ggplot syntax: `ggplot() + geom_point(data = df_A, aes(x,y)) + etc`

Comment: thanks, edited to include your example first, and remove the subsetting function.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to get the data into one data.frame. Here's an example using `ldply()` from `plyr()`, assuming your data.frames are named `d1` and `d2`:

```
library(plyr)
> d3 <- ldply(list(d1 = d2, d2 = d2))
> rbind(head(d3,2), tail(d3,2))
   .id column.x column.y
1   d1     0.13     1.24
2   d1     0.34     1.16
9   d2     0.54     0.99
10  d2     0.69     1.01
```

Or simply pass the different datasets to different geoms when plotting. Something like this:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = d1, aes(column.x, column.y)) +
  geom_point(data = d2, aes(column.x, column.y), colour = "red")
```

Comment: `reshape2::melt(list(d1 = d2, d2 = d2))` is perhaps more efficient for this than ldply (untested).

Comment: That works fine too.  I really appreciate your help and the tutorial link info. I tried joining only the dataset A points with a line in the plot as follows (without success): 'ggplot(data=df, aes(x=col1, y=col2, col=dataset, size=dataset)) + geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(name="dataset", labels = c("Data A","Data B"), values=c("blue", "darkgreen")) + 
  scale_size_manual(name="dataset", labels = c("Data A","Data B"), values=c(10, 5)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_text(data = df,aes(x=col1,y=col2, label=d1)) + 
  xlab("xxxx") + ylab("yyyy")'.   Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to plot points as unfilled circles with a rim of color using ggplots? I came across fill =NA, which I tired and does not seem to work for me.